# How to display only the end result in a while loop PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

If I make a loop go through a certain amount of ids in a database how can I only echo it once and not everytime it loops through a id?? My code is shown under:

```
$query = "SELECT userid FROM users ";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "There are currently <b> ". $row['userid'] ."</b> users registered in our server database!";
echo "<br />";  
}
```

Comment: if you want to get number of rows in database use Select count(1) as total from users.. No need to use while loop then. Option 2 use mysql_num_rows

Comment: Stop using mysql. it is deprecated use mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do a `SELECT COUNT()` to get the number of users.

Comment: Thanks, how could I be so dumb!!

Answer (score 0):

i realized that you just want the users count

you should use

```
$query = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM users ";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "There are currently <b> ". $row['count'] ."</b> users registered in our server database!";
echo "<br />";  
}
```

Comment: the query will return only one row. So why use while loop.Also count(1) is more efficient from count(*)

Comment: count( * ) -v- count(1) there is no difference (* does not evaluate each and every field or cause massive I/O, it's a myth I'm afraid)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNT(userid)` instead of `mysql_fetch_array()`

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(userid) FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Also can use `MAX(userid)` if it is an `int` type

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(userid) as total_users FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$total_user = $row['total_users'];
```